# Type I error control for multiple comparisons

Tags: multiple-comparisons

In statistics, there is approach, aka, fixed-sequence hirarchical approach to control the Type I error when it comes to multiple tests for different variables. For example, there are 3 tests to be tested, and the test sequence is pre-defined as H1 -> H2 ->H3, that means, H2 will be tested if and only if H1 is statistically significant at significance level of 0.05, and H3 will be tested if and only if each of H1 and H2 is signficant at signficance level of 0.05.

My question is why this can control the overal type I error at 0.05, and why the alpha is not 'used' and can be re-allocated to H2 when we claim H1 is significant when P value is <0.05?

Also, what is the relationship between this fixed sequence hierarchical approach and the Closed Testing Procedure?

Thank you very much.

Comment: I believe the point is that the family-wise error rate is the probability of making *at least* one type I assertion, so as long as each hypothesis is controlled at that level you will only proceed if it was a true or false positive (i.e. you would already have a type I assertion in the second case but the next tests then can't add to the FWER defined as such).

Comment: I love seeing the word "assertion" here.  Type I assertion probabilities are typically called type I errors but this is misleading because they are not probabilities of errors.  For that reason, multiple testing procedures and alpha control loses a lot of appeal.  See [here](https://hbiostat.org/bbr/alpha).